# How to handle Request with JSON and Multipart File in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I am trying to create a REST API in the format which will accept request data with both JSON and MultipartFile type.

THis is my request which will be in following format in POSTMAN:
[image: REquest Format i PostMan]

My POJO classes are as follows:

**Class:Organisation**

```
public class Organisation
{
    priavet int org_id;
    private MultipartFile organisationRegistrationDocument;
    private Teachers[]

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Class: Teachers**

```
class Teachers{

    private String teacherId;
    private MultipartFile teacherPhoto;

    // getters and setters
}
```

My controller Class is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers = {"content-type=multipart/mixed","content-type=multipart/form-data"})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> testUpload(@RequestBody Organisation org) {
        return null;
    }
```

Error Thrown from POSTMAN:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-03T07:38:30.439+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required request part 'org' is not present",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

So anyone can kindly guide me what can I am doing wrong due to which I am not able to achieve the desired result to process request of the above form?

Comment: Replace `@Request` with `@RequestBody`

Comment: Sorry it is RequestBody I am using it only.It was an copy paste error .Even with RequestBody it throws same error.

Comment: Try using `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`

Comment: Spring doesn't know that all these data in form are used to compose an object of type Organisation

Comment: Hi Maruthi, By using @Modelattribute I was able to hit the controller but the attribute "Teachers" in Organisation class is binded with null value can you kindly help me if there is any mistake with POSTMAN request format?

Comment: @Maruthi Thanks alot for the guidance and time able to achieve the result.

Comment: @SrikR did you resolve this issue?